# Ip Address is not changed if imported a guest in VirualBox

Tags: server, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ip-address, redhat

I had exported my VirtualBox guest Operating System which was Red Hat 6 to import it into other machine. My IP address in this machine was 192.168.15.117. I Started my import to other machine and after completion, i switched it on and found that it also has same IP address. I wanted to use both guest OS at the same time using sql developer, but i think it may conflict.

Comment: If your VM network settings is set to `NAT` or `HOST-ONLY` then it will not conflict. If set to `BRIDGED` then it will definitely conflict. If unsure, you should change the IP address of the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check this checkbox before you do the machine clone:
[image]

What it does is it will give the new machine a new MAC address. You have same IP in two machines because they're same MAC.

Hopes It would help you.